# How to handle this *very* large array?

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, memory

I've made a script that basically scans every IP in a specified subnet for a specific network vulnerability in the webserver, it is working just fine but i'm having an issue that the program is consuming somewhere between 6GB of memory when a subnet with a lot of IPs are requested, for example: 127.0.0.0/8 that has a range between 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255 (16 million IPs I think),
I am storing all the IPs on a array upon program start, and I think that may be the problem, as the array would have 16 million IPs... How can I optimize it to consume less memory?

Here is my current code:

```
import gc
import requests
import ipaddress
import sys
import time
from bounded_pool_executor import BoundedProcessPoolExecutor
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()


ip_list = []
vulnerable_ip_list = []
header = { 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Missing argument...")
    exit()

def initialize_ip_list():
    for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network((sys.argv[1])):
        ip_list.append(str(ip))

def initialize_threads():
    futures = []
    with BoundedProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=int(sys.argv[2])) as executor:
        for ip in ip_list:
            executor.submit(scan_ip, ip)

def scan_ip(ip):
    host = "http://" + str(ip) + "/vulnerableurl/"
    print("Trying to fetch: " + host)
    try:
        r = requests.get(host, headers=header, verify=False, timeout=5)
        body = r.text
        if 'vulnerable page' in body.lower():
            print('Vulnerability found on: ' + host)
            with open("output.txt", "a") as txt_file:
                txt_file.write(host + "\n")
    except:
        pass

print("Initializing IPs at " + str(sys.argv[1]))
initialize_ip_list()
print("Initializing work with " + str(sys.argv[2]) + " threads")
initialize_threads()
```

Comment: Instead of populating the list, iterate over the network directly. Also you are having mostly I/O. Consider using threads instead of processes.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i was able to optimize it by iterating over network directly as said by @KlausD. !

Answer (score 0):

Think about whether you need to keep the list of ip addresses around.

Instead of creating the `ip_list` object and populating it with the IPv4Network object in `initialize_ip_list()` perhaps just use the IPv4Network object directly in your `initialize_threads()`:

```
def initialize_threads():
    futures = []
    with BoundedProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=int(sys.argv[2])) as executor:
        for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network((sys.argv[1])):
            executor.submit(scan_ip, ip)
```

This way they won't be kept around - just used for the scan and then dropped.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was able to go from ~6GB usage to ~740MB usage !